# Compare two datatables

Tags: asp.net, listview, datatable, selection

i have two datatables with only one column each. i wanted to compare those two columns in two datatables. here is the example.. i am using C#.Net and WPF for achieving this.

```
dt1 
apple
orange
peach
banana

dt2
apple
peach
mango
apricot
```

now i want to compare dt2 with dt1.
dt2 is bound to a list box. so once i match with dt1, the unmatched items selection should be diabled. here i wanted the mango and apricot selection to be disabled..

hope i am clear..

Answer (score 0):

Populate the list box with items from dt2, but enable only the items returned by `dt1 join dt2 on dt1.column_name = dt2.column_name`.

Comment: do you have any example code for that?? i am a beginner in C#.. Thanks for the help